# Is there a name for the coordinate on a function which has maximum curvature?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, terminology, curvature

I found out how to find the maximum curvature, by differentiating the curve function. I am wondering if there is a mathematical term, or if there isn't one what is the most elegant way to represent it? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A point on a curve where the curvature is at a local maximum or minimum is called a [vertex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28curve%29).

Comment: that does not answer the question at all. For example on the graph of e to the power x, there is a point where the curvature is a maximum at i think it was, 1/2ln(1/2). It does not coincide with an extremum

Comment: When I write "the curvature is at a local maximum or minimum", I mean the curvature attains those things. There is no other concept of maximum or minimum to consider here; unless you bring up graphs as an example and get confused.

Comment: I see. Thank you